# Reactive form with dynamic controls - issue with fetching the form value

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that is dynamically populated.

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="save();" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">Steps</td> 
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">Estimated Completion Date:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">{{product.number}}. {{product.name}}</td>           
            <td style="padding-right: 20px">
                <md-input-container>
                    <input mdInput formControlName="estimatedDate" [mdDatepicker]="estimatedDate" placeholder="Choose a date" [value]="product.estimatedDate">
                    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="estimatedDate" [value]="product.estimatedDate"></button>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-datepicker #estimatedDate></md-datepicker>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button md-raised-button (click)="save()">Done</button>
</form>
```

On Save, I want to create an array of the form values.

```
this.products.forEach(product=> {
            this.resultArray.push({
                number: product.number,
                estimatedDate: this.productForm.value['estimatedDate']
            });

        } )
```

I have 2 issues:
- foreach loops through the products variable twice, so I get double the number of items in the array.
- the estimatedDate field is undefined. Am I accessing the form variable correctly?   `this.productForm.value['estimatedDate']`

Comment: Hey Jay, did either answer help you, or do you need further assistance? :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about referencing the form variable ... the `get` method is recommended:

```
heroForm.get('name').value
```

So yours would look something like this:

```
this.productForm.get('estimatedDate').value
```

Regarding the first question ... if you are using reactive forms, you shouldn't be using data binding. So I'm a bit confused by your code. But check both the `products` variable and the `resultArray` variable before the loop to see if they are causing the for/each issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really having a reactive form going on there. I would suggest you refactor your code, so that you are indeed having a reactive form. So we build the form, as well as we iterate your products array and make it a formarray. Seems you want to exclude `name` from the formarray, but if we want to use it in template, we need it. So we can disable that field, which excludes it from the form array, but we can get the value by using `getRawValue()`.

`fb` below refers to `FormBuilder`:

```ts
ngOnInit() {    
  this.productForm = this.fb.group({
    products: this.fb.array([])
  });
  // iterate products and create a formgroup for each object, pushed to array
  this.products.forEach(product => {
    this.productForm.get('products').push(this.fb.group({
      number:product.number, name:{value: product.name, disabled:true}, 
      estimatedDate:product.estimatedDate}))
  })
}
```

Then in your template we iterate that formarray, mark the formgroup with `index` and lastly display the formcontrolnames. The important part of your table would then look like this:

```html
<tbody formArrayName="products">
 <tr *ngFor="let product of productForm.controls.products.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
   <td>{{product.value.number}}. {{product.getRawValue().name}}</td>           
   <td>
     <md-input-container>
       <input mdInput formControlName="estimatedDate" [mdDatepicker]="estimatedDate" placeholder="Choose a date">
       <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="estimatedDate"></button>
     </md-input-container>
     <md-datepicker #estimatedDate></md-datepicker>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

*Now* we truly have a reactive form! :) And the form object should now contain the object you want, or `this.productForm.value.products` is the array you want.